# CoreBluetooth scan for particular services

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

i'm trying to search for a peripheral with particular service UUID, and i enter the line of code as follow but it pop out error, did i miss out something? can someone suggest please.

```
centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([NSArray arrayWithObject [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@ "180A"]], options: nil)
```

Comment: Could you post the error log?

Comment: the program cannot execute at all, error shown "expected ',' separator"

Comment: You seem to be mixing Swift and Objective C Syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems to be syntax error that what i understood from info u provided.
try this code..

let serviceUUIDs:[AnyObject] = [CBUUID(string: "180D")]
centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(serviceUUIDs, options: nil)

Comment: Yup, it is a syntax error that ti mix up objective-c with swift! thank dude!

Answer (score 1):

you mixed swift's syntax with Objective-C's syntax,no wonder there is an error.

IN  Objective-C:

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject :[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@ "180A"]]  options:nil];
```

IN swift:

```
  centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([CBUUID(string: "180A")], options: nil)
```